# Replace a range of cells with one value if that value appears more than once in the range

Tags: vba, list, replace, lookup

```
Company Contact Contact Contact Contact Contact
Company 1   Jon James   Jon Jon Mark
Company 2   Mark    Eric    Jon Eric    
Company 3   Jon Mark    Eric        
Company 4   Jon             
Company 5   Mark    Eric    James   James
```

I have a list of unique values in column A (company names). I then I have horizontal lists of contacts.

I want to look up the range of cells ( for company 1 it would be B1:E1), and if a name appears more than once (ex. for company 1, Jon) I wanted to replace B1 with Jon and clear all other cells. If no name appears more than once, I want to leave all the values the same.

Comment: Presumably you want the replacement to be the name that occurs the most times?

Comment: Yes, if a name appears more than once, I want to replace with that name (and clear all other duplicates and unique names). So for company 1, I would want to clear all cells and have "Jon" appear alone. In cases where all are unique (like in company 3), I want to leave all unique names and not replace them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using a dictionary (requires you to add a reference to microsoft scripting runtime via the tools > references , in the VBE.)

```
Sub test()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsSource As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wsSource = wb.Worksheets("Sheet6")

Dim loopRange As Range
Dim currRow As Range

Set loopRange = wsSource.Range("B2:F6")

For Each currRow In loopRange.Rows

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(currRow) > 1 Then

        If FindFrequency(currRow)(1) > 1 Then

            With wsSource
                .Cells(currRow.Row, 2) = FindFrequency(currRow)(0)
                .Range(.Cells(currRow.Row, 3), .Cells(currRow.Row, 6)).ClearContents
            End With
        End If

    End If

Next currRow

End Sub

Function FindFrequency(currRow As Range) As Variant 'Adapted from here https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1581-excel-find-most-common-value.html#a2

Dim rng As Range
Dim dic As Object 'late binding
Dim xMax As Long
Dim xOutValue As String
Dim xValue As String
Dim xCount As Long

Set dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

On Error Resume Next

xMax = 0
xOutValue = ""

For Each rng In currRow.Columns

    xValue = rng.Text

    If xValue <> "" Then

        dic(xValue) = dic(xValue) + 1
        xCount = dic(xValue)

        If xCount > xMax Then
            xMax = xCount
            xOutValue = xValue
        End If

    End If

Next rng

FindFrequency = Array(xOutValue, xMax)

Set dic = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the worksheet function `CountIf` we can determine which contact to use as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetContactName()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, sht As Worksheet, lastrow As Long, tempvalue As String

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    For j = 2 To 6
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 6)), Cells(i, j)) > 1 Then
            tempvalue = Cells(i, j)
            Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 6)).ClearContents
            Cells(i, 2) = tempvalue
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

[image][image]